# Mocking a spring interface

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito, powermock

I have a service with an `@Autowired` repository that I would like to mock with PowerMock. It is ofcourse quite easy to just create the mock, but the problem is injecting it.

My testcase must start 2 different servers so I run code like this:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(Server.class)
    .profiles("test")
    .properties("server.port=" + port)
    .run();
```

And so I don't really have a reference to the repository that I want to replace with a mock one, and thus a `Whitebox` solution probably doesn't work.

I've tried doing something like this

```
Queue mockQueue = mock(Queue.class);
whenNew(Queue.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockQueue);
```

but since the `Queue` is an interface this doesn't really work. And I have no implementation to go mock either.

So I am kind of stuck here, and am wondering if this can be done and how?

For reference this is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface Queue extends JpaRepository<QueueItem, Long> {
...
}
```

for the sake of it I tried spying on the containing class like this:

```
QueueService queueService = spy(new QueueService());
whenNew(QueueService.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(queueService);
```

and then set the internal state:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(queueService, "queue", mockQueue);
```

And this works if I create a new `QueueService` from the test, but if I run normaly then the `QueueService` will not be a spied object

Oh an my test class is currently annotated like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(QueueService.class)
```

All the dependencies that I have:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentracing-spring-web-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
  <version>2.27</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
```

Also quite interesting is that the class is loaded by a `MockClassLoader`

Comment: Could you try using @MockBean annotation for Queue interface?

Comment: @staszko032 I tried it but I am getting exceptions. Probably because of my test setup(I have updated my question with it). `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;`

Comment: That looks like a classpath configuration issue. What spring & mockito/powermockito versions are you using?